# Rotate a matrix(2D Array) by 45 degrees in c++

Tags: c++, math, matrix, multidimensional-array, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a matrix(MxN)by 45 degrees.
For example:

```
|a|b|c|d|e|
|f|g|h|i|j|
|k|l|m|n|o|
```

Would be rotated to this:

```
| | |a| | | | |
| |f| |b| | | |
|k| |g| |c| | |
| |l| |h| |d| |
| | |m| |i| |e|
| | | |n| |j| |
| | | | |o| | |
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
EDIT: My look on the problem.

I have been thinking about this and this is the formula i ended up with:
f(i,j) = (i+j,m-1-i+j)

But the problem I run into is if I were to do this rotation 2 times i wouldn't get a 90 degree rotation.

Comment: @Raw N I'm supposed to right a function that does that

Comment: You are supposed to present the work you've done so far. The [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) has got you covered.

Comment: @RawN `std::rotate` does not give the same result as the OP requires.

Comment: @RawN I didn't post any work cause it's not worth posting it's just the reading of the initial matrix[m][n] and creating of the new one in which i would place the rotated matrix - matrix1[m+n-1][m+n-1]

Comment: @Saizaku Then you should at least present how you think you should solve the problem, even if there's no code.

Comment: Use openCv, take a picture of the sheet of paper where you wrote this matrix, then load it in and use openCv to rotate the image 45 deg. Then print the page.

Comment: your input and output matrices have different dimensions, so when you say you want to apply rotation 2 times, do you want a function which takes 3x5 matrix, spits out 7x7, then takes 7x7 and spits out what? another 7X7 or 5x3? i doubt there is a single transformation which does that.
Also, the transformation you want is not technically a rotation, as they are supposed to preserve dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to rotate a point (x,y) by 45° you would use the formula

```
x' = cos(45°) * x - sin(45°) * y
y' = sin(45°) * x + cos(45°) * y
```

Now we know cos(45°) = sin(45°) = 1 / sqrt(2). So if (x,y) are integer coordinated then (x',y') will not be integers due to the sqrt(2) factor.

If you want to rotate elements in a matrix so the points lie in a matrix you effectively want to rotate integer coordinates to integer coordinates (taking the central point h as the origin). So in some sense, you are asking the impossible.

There are two ways around this.

1) Drop the requirement for integer coordinates. Not possible if you want to fit the results in a array. If you array represents the pixels in an image this is what you would do. Once rotated you need to calculate the resulting pixel values by averaging the surrounding pixels.

2) Multiply the results by scale factor of sqrt(2). This is basically what you have done. If you calculate the distance in your rotated grid using Pythagoras then the distances of adjacent points will be sqrt(2).

If you then repeat this twice you would find the distances would be doubled.

One possible solution would be to use your algorithm and then divide all the coordinates by 2.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion, the work around I came up with is that I had a separate function that would rotate it by 90 degrees so if I need a 125 degree rotation i would rotate it by 90 and the by 45 degrees

Answer (score 0):

Try this transition:

mat[x][y] -> mat[x+y][x-y] or mat[x-y][x+y] (depends which direction you want to rotate)

Something like this mat[m+i-j][i+j] = oldmat[i][j] will work to handle negative indices